# Inserting multiple values into a column in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL database. I have to insert two set of data into it.

1. Programmes
2. Courses

Each programme includes more than one course. A course can be included by more than one programme. If i create two tables - Programmes and Courses, Is it possible to insert multiple values into the column named courses in Program table? If yes how? If no,  Which is best way to represent this data in a mysql database?
**I have an idea**
Create a third table called Programmes_and_Courses with two columns - programme id which point to Programmes table and courseid which points to Course table. To insert a programme p1 which consist of two courses c1 and c2, insert two rows to the table Programmes_and_Courses as follows:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iJFd.png)

Is this a good idea? If yes, Can you suggest a better name for the third table?
Thanks.

Comment: That's called a "many-to-many" relationship and is the standardized approach to doing this. The table name convention is usually `courses_programmes` which is each table name with `_` in between and tables appear alphabetically.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a third table is definitely a way to go. This kind of table is sometimes known as a *junction table.* Following are the benefits:

- It will allow you to independently insert records in `Programs` and `Courses` table.
- It will keep Programs and Courses decoupled from each other and keep your schema in 3rd Normal form.

As far as name is concerned, you can go with `program_course` with `program_id` and `course_id` as columns.